# Trying to create class that can be passed between app domains as parameter c#

Tags: c#, serialization, appdomain

That is what i am trying to do:

I created the class that i want to be the parameter that will be passed between two app domains. In the file ClassLibrary1.dll:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {          
        public string mystr = "NotWorking!";

         public MyClass(string _mystr)
         {
            mystr = _mystr;
         }            
         public override string ToString()
         {
             return mystr;
         }
}
```

Then i created another class that will be the class that will recive MyClass as parameter in otherdomainclass.dll:

```
public class OtherDomainClass : MarshalByRefObject, IOtherDomainClass
{
    #region Implementation of IOtherDomainClass

    private MyClass my;
    public MyClass getParam()
    {
        return my;
    }

    public void setParam(MyClass _param)
    {
        my = _param;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and defined interface for that class in in iotherdomainclass.dll:

```
public interface IOtherDomainClass
{
    MyClass getParam();
    void setParam(MyClass _param);
}
```

and now I am trying to run the following test :

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void PassMyclassBetweenDomains()
    {
        domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(appDomainName);
        otherClass = domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(location, "OtherDomain.OtherDomainClass") as IOtherDomainClass;
        Assert.IsNotNull(otherClass);
        otherClass.setParam(new MyClass("Working!"));
        string sparam = otherClass.getParam().ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(sparam, "Working!");
        AppDomain.Unload(domain); 
    }
```

the test fails with following error:

```
Test method SerizalizableDataTypesTest.ParamCollectionTest.PassMyclassBetweenDomains threw exception 
    System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly        'ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Sorry about the long story I am not sure what part I am doing wrong. Or if all the code is wrong from the beginning could you please help me to recreate it.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please add the full exception and stacktrace.

Comment: Found the interesting issue here when I run the scenario in console application it works fine but when I run in in unit test it throws the exception that I wrote.

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?  Can you post the full exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `MyClass` type you created is in a assembly that has not yet been loaded in the second AppDomain, consider loading that assembly directly in the 2nd AppDomain.

Your example class is more complicated than it needs to be because you are not doing anything that requires custom serialization/deserialization code.  This will be easier to maintain:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
   public string mystr = "NotWorking!";
   public MyClass(string _mystr)
   {
      mystr = _mystr;
   }
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return mystr;
   }
}
```

Comment: Checked it now in modules window I can see two apperiences of ClassLibrary1.dll. Could it be other reason you can think of? thank you

Comment: When in doubt, believe the exception.  It seems that it should be loaded, but what can it hurt to be sure?  Look specifically at the Version and public key token.  foreach (var assembly in appDomain2.GetAssemblies()) Console.WriteLine (a); // It may be that you have compiled the apps against different versions of the ClassLibrary1 dll.

Comment: OK I think we are getting closer to the problem . Your foreach throws exception : Could not load file or assembly 'OtherDomainClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file

Comment: Can you cause the foreach Assembly code to run in the 2nd AppDomain?  You can also print out assembly.Location.  This will tell you where on disk the assembly is located.

Comment: Ran it the output i get is : that ClassLibrary1.dll is loaded

Comment: Can you add the full exception and stack trace?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to change the implementation to something a little simpler.  I'll edit my response.

Comment: @agent-j Sorry for bothering it works and i do not know why when i wil know i will post here. The foreach loop thrown exception because it could not print in current domain dlls that loaded in other domain.

Comment: @Sergey Kucher, good luck!  Assembly not found errors are usually tricky to find.

Comment: @agent-j : Found the interesting issue here when I run the scenario in console application it works fine but when I run in in unit test it throws the exception that I wrote.